# Python dictionary Keys to new dict

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary and a set as follows:

```
fundprices = {
'A' : 20,
'B' : 20,
'C' : 10,
'D' : 15,
'E' : 10,
'F' : 15,
'G' : 35,
'H' : 20,
'I' : 10,
'J' : 5
}

dollaramount = {
100000.0, 
100000.0, 
50000.0, 
300000.0, 
50000.0, 
100000.0, 
100000.0, 
150000.0, 
50000.0, 
0
}
```

And I am trying to create a third dictionary that is the result of the set divided by the dictionary, with the following code:

```
orderamount = []

for i in fundprices.key(), dollaramount.key():
    orderamount.append(dollaramount[i] / fundprices[i])

print orderamount
```

Where `orderamount` has the same keys as fund prices. However, I am getting 'dict' object has no attributes as a result. In this case, dollaramount is a set created from another calculation from 2 dictionaries. If it is easier to add keys when the set dollaramount is created, let me know. How do I fix this?

Comment: the second object is not a dictionary. it is a set.

Comment: Actually, it's not even a set - there's a surplus closing bracket there. Also I'f you're dividing the first by the second, you're going to get a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: How does `dollaramount` relate to `fundprices`? Recall, dictionaries are unordered.'

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga:  in the 3.6 Python C implementation the keys are now in insertion order.  That is not guaranteed for future implementations so I agree it should not be relied on.

Comment: @cdarke yes, and all documentation regarding the new implementation *warns specifically not to rely on it because it is an implementation detail*. Furthermore, the OP is also using a `set`, which remains unordered.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point. I guess what I'm asking is when I append values to a new dictionary, how to make sure they have keys. dollar amount is the result of an appending of the multiplication of a dictionary containing weightings and an integer amount assigned to a variable. Should I post the code?

Comment: @AlexBambu I'm not sure I understand you. The things you are saying don't make sense because you are using non-standard terminology. One doesn't `append` values to a dictionary, that is a `list` method. If I interpret it as "add a new key-value pair" to the dictionary, then I don't know what you mean by "make sure they have keys". You cannot have just a key in a dictionary, it is *always a mapping from keys to values*.

Comment: @AlexBambu Lastly, I have no idea what " dollar amount is the result of an appending of the multiplication of a dictionary containing weightings and an integer amount assigned to a variable" means. Dictionaries don't support multiplication, so you have to be *specific* about what you are doing. It helps to give a **valid** example of input, and expected outputs.

Comment: Finally, I'm fairly certain that `for i in fundprices.key(), dollaramount.key():` is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Huh okay. Thanks for clarification. Will do more learning and attempt it again.

Comment: @AlexBambu I think at the very least you need to be able to describe what you want/ what you are doing in words and barring that, with an example that provides a valid input, expected output, current output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can I reach out to you by email for further clarification? I think I need some more explanation.

Comment: @AlexBambu, Please update the question.

Comment: @AlexFung I will ask a separate question in a bit. The problem I'm having stems from before the nonsense code above was born.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
fundprices = {
    'A' : 20,
    'B' : 20,
    'C' : 10,
    'D' : 15,
    'E' : 10,
    'F' : 15,
    'G' : 35,
    'H' : 20,
    'I' : 10,
    'J' : 5
    }

dollaramount = [
    100000.0, 
    100000.0, 
    50000.0, 
    300000.0, 
    50000.0, 
    100000.0, 
    100000.0, 
    150000.0, 
    50000.0, 
    0]
ordered_fundprices = OrderedDict(sorted(fundprices.items()))
for i, j in zip(ordered_fundprices.keys(), dollaramount):
    print i, j

for i, j in zip(ordered_fundprices.itervalues(), dollaramount):
    print j / i
```

Did you wanted such a result ?

```
A 100000.0
B 100000.0
C 50000.0
D 300000.0
E 50000.0
F 100000.0
G 100000.0
H 150000.0
I 50000.0
J 0
5000.0
5000.0
5000.0
20000.0
5000.0
6666.66666667
2857.14285714
7500.0
5000.0
0
```

Comment: You cannot rely on this behavior - dictionaries are unordered and this will give random results on different runs/different python versions etc. As an aside, you don't need to use the `keys` method to iterate over `dict` keys - that happens automatically, and is inefficient in Python 2 and unnecessary and redundant in Python 3.

Comment: No, the result will always be the same. Because order of keys is specified once and same till the end of this object's life. And I will agree, it's not ordered. Notice the same order when running this loop as a third one:
`for i, j in zip(fundprices.itervalues(), dollaramount):
    print j / i
    a.append(j/i)`
`for i, j in zip(fundprices.keys(), a):
    print i, j`

Comment: But you have no way of knowing what ratios you will get *until you run the code*, and it is unlikely the OP wants random ratios. So yes, as long as you don't modify the dictionary, you will get the same result, but you cannot know what that result will be, *because dictionaries are unordered*.

Comment: For example, if I run your code, for the first loop you had above, I get `A 100000.0 G 100000.0  E 50000.0 ...` instead of `A 100000.0 C 100000.0 B 50000.0 ...`

Comment: I agree @juanpa.arrivillaga, better use OrderedDict and be sure about the order of keys in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list` instead of `set` as `dollaramount` actually euqals to,

```
set([0, 50000.0, 100000.0, 150000.0, 300000.0])
```

Then, we have,

```
orderamount = [amount/t[1] for amount, t in zip(dollaramount, sorted(fundprices.items()))]

print(orderamount)
# [5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 20000.0, 5000.0, 6666.666666666667, 2857.1428571428573, 7500.0, 5000.0, 0]
```

If you wanna have a dictionary that remembers the order that keys were first inserted, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't make sense to put the result fo `sorted(fundprices.items())` in a `OrderedDict`, and the subsequently iterate over the `items`... just use `sortd(fundprices.items())` directly...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thx. I did it for the readability purpose. Anyway, I've just updated my answer.